# Is there any way I can have a tooltip with an input and sorting both applied to the same header in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, sorting, vue.js, vuejs2, tooltip

```
 <th v-for="value in tableHeaders" v-bind:key="value" @click="sorting(value)">{{value}}
 <span class="tooltiptext">
<input type="text" class="form-field" placeholder="Search" v-model="filterthese[value]"><br>
<button class="button button-theme" @click.prevent="applyFilter()">Apply </button>
 </th>
```

//sorting function
//apply filter function

the problem is that although sorting works here and i can see the tooltip of input for all headers but i am unable to write anything inside the tooltip since as i click to write, it gives a call to the sorting function which sorts and reloads the page.

Comment: You will want to have something like `<input @click.stop ...>` since the click on the input will propagate to the `th` and trigger the `@click="sorting(value)"` event listener.

Comment: I tried @click.stop() on the input tag but that didn't work.

Comment: Also the applyFilter function doesn't work too. Instead sorting function is called.

Comment: Please reproduce this in a codesandbox so I can see exactly what your logic is, then I can help.